# SPARQL counting triples in multiple graphs

Tags: count, sum, sparql

I want to count triples in multiple graphs which are of a certain class and sum it up. I manage to count the triples of this class in each graph but I don't manage to calculate the total.

Initial query:

```sql
PREFIX locah: <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/>
PREFIX bs: <http://localhost:3030/alod/bs>
PREFIX ne: <http://localhost:3030/alod/ne>

SELECT (count(?sBS) as ?BScount) (count(?sNE) AS ?NEcount) WHERE {
  {
    GRAPH bs: {
      ?sBS a locah:ArchivalResource
    }
  } UNION {
    GRAPH ne: {
      ?sNE a locah:ArchivalResource
    }
  }
}
```

My idea was to simply use the `SUM()` function as well so the SELECT would be like this:

```sql
SELECT (count(?sBS) as ?BScount) (count(?sNE) AS ?NEcount) (SUM(?NEcount ?BScount) AS ?total )WHERE {
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

And a related question: Why do I need the UNION? If I execute it without UNION it seems to come up with a very high triple count which doesn't make much sense and the count is twice the same.

You can try it on my SPARQL endpoint: [http://data.alod.ch/sparql/](http://data.alod.ch/sparql/?outputFormat=table&query=%0APREFIX+locah%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.archiveshub.ac.uk%2Fdef%2F%3E%0APREFIX+bs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Falod%2Fbs%3E%0APREFIX+ne%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Falod%2Fne%3E%0A%0ASELECT+(count(%3FsBS)+as+%3FBScount)+(count(%3FsNE)+AS+%3FNEcount)+WHERE+%7B%0A++%7B%0A++++GRAPH+bs%3A+%7B%0A++++++%3FsBS+a+locah%3AArchivalResource%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D+UNION+%7B%0A++++GRAPH+ne%3A+%7B%0A++++++%3FsNE+a+locah%3AArchivalResource%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%0A%7D&contentTypeConstruct=text%2Fturtle&contentTypeSelect=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.alod.ch%2Falod%2Fsparql&requestMethod=POST&tabTitle=Query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use an aggregate in the projection, you have to partition, or group, the solutions by distinct values of some of the variables.  If you don't specify a **group by** clause, then the grouping is implicit.  In this case, you have (at least) two options.  One would be to use two subqueries, as in:

```sql
select ?acount ?bcount (?acount + ?bcount as ?totalCount) where {
  { select (count(*) as ?acount) where {
      graph :a { ... } }
  { select (count(*) as ?bcount) where {
      graph :b { ... } }
}
```

I think that's probably the simplest and most self-explanatory option.  The other option, as you've noted, is to use a union:

```sql
select (count(?a) as ?acount)
       (count(?b) as ?bcount)
       (?acount + ?bcount as ?totalCount)
where {
  { graph :a { ?a ... } }
  union
  { graph :b { ?b ... } }
}
```

The reason that something like

```sql
select (count(?a) as ?acount)
       (count(?b) as ?bcount)
       (?acount + ?bcount as ?totalCount)
where {
  graph :a { ?a ... }
  graph :b { ?b ... }
}
```

*doesn't* work is that you end up with the *Cartesian product* of ?a and ?b values.  That is, suppose that there are two values for ?a and three values for ?b.  Then you end up with six rows in the table:

```
a1, b1  
a1, b2 
a1, b3
a2, b1  
a2, b2 
a2, b3
```

Each of these rows is unique, so if you use the implicit **group by**, you'll have six a's and six b's, which isn't really what you want.  You could still do this however, using **distinct**:

```sql
select (count(distinct ?a) as ?acount)
       (count(distinct ?b) as ?bcount)
       (?acount + ?bcount as ?totalCount)
where {
  #-- ...
}
```

### Types of Queries

#### Type 1: Subqueries

```sql
SELECT ?BScount ?NEcount (?BScount + ?NEcount as ?totalCount)
WHERE {
  { select (count(*) as ?BScount) WHERE {
      GRAPH bs: { ?sBS a locah:ArchivalResource }
    } }
  { select (count(*) as ?NEcount) WHERE {
      GRAPH ne: { ?sNE a locah:ArchivalResource }
    } }
}
```

#### Type 2: Union

```sql
SELECT (count(?sBS) as ?BScount)
       (count(?sNE) AS ?NEcount)
       (?BScount + ?NEcount as ?totalCount)
WHERE {
  { GRAPH bs: { ?sBS a locah:ArchivalResource } }
  UNION
  { GRAPH ne: { ?sNE a locah:ArchivalResource } }
}
```

#### Type 3: Cartesian Product and Distinct

```sql
SELECT (count(distinct ?sBS) as ?BScount)
       (count(distinct ?sNE) AS ?NEcount)
       (?BScount + ?NEcount as ?totalCount)
WHERE {
  { GRAPH bs: { ?sBS a locah:ArchivalResource } }
  { GRAPH ne: { ?sNE a locah:ArchivalResource } }
}
```

Comment: Hey Joshua, thanks a lot for the very elaborate answer! Works great and learned new ways!

Comment: Hi  I have one question can anybody tell me which one from above solutions is better in performance wise ? thank you.